# Is there a way to re-write this query without subqueries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table of employees from HR schema (oracle). This is how I completed the task (select employees with minimal salary in their departments, if they belong to any of them)

```
    SELECT D.employee_id,D.Last_name,D.salary,D.department_id
    FROM [HelpDatabase].[dbo].[Employees] D,
         [HelpDatabase].[dbo].[Employees] E
    WHERE D.department_id IS NOT NULL 
      AND E.department_id IS NOT NULL
      AND D.employee_id=E.employee_id
      AND D.salary=ANY (
          SELECT MIN(E.salary) 
          FROM [HelpDatabase].[dbo].[Employees] 
          GROUP BY E.department_id)
```

Query working correctly, but I've been told there's a way to do it without using subquery.

Comment: bs - that query cannot work correctly, because it has syntax errors.

Comment: @mathguy - only in the badly-obfuscated table names... (they're almost the standard employees and departments tables, but why  departments would have an employee_id column is a bit of a mystery)

Comment: @mathguy you're right, edited it.

Comment: @AlexPoole - Not really (unless you count the standalone word TABLE as part of table names).

Comment: @Shady119 - if you have a query that works, why can't you copy and paste it? Or is your problem different from what you posted?

Comment: @mathguy - yes; it's annoyingly common for people here to replace their real table names with 'table' even though that's illegal; and as here to use the same bad name for at least two real tables. I agree hiding stuff is unhelpful to say the least, but doesn't mean their real query doesn't work. And agree it would be nice to see the real query of course...

Comment: Your query returns false-positives. If you have an employee with a salary that equales to a minimum salary of **another** department, you will get him as well.

Comment: @mathguy posted original query. I thought that replacing it with word 'table' would make it easier to read.

Comment: Oh, yes, and it's false positive. I made a stupid assumption that it was correct.

Comment: I think I understand "select employees with minimal salary in their departments", but what does ", if they belong to any of them" mean?

Comment: By the way: Why are you using `[` and `]`? And why are you joining tables with a comma? I take it that you are *currently* learning SQL, but this syntax was mainly taught, before it was made redundant (which was in 1992; some DBMS took a while to adopt it though). And what are you using the self-join for? I see no sense in it. (And I still doubt this is your working query, seeing still the keyword `table` in it.)

Comment: This syntax is yelling **SQL Server**

Comment: Yes, it's sql server. Guy who told me to do it without subqueries using oracle DB with SQL developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you simply want to find the employees that earn the lowest salaries in their departments:

Yes, this can be done without a subquery. The idea is that you can look for employees for which not exists another employee in the same department and a lower salary:

```
select *
from emp
where not exists
(
  select *
  from emp less
  where less.department_id = emp.department_id and less.salary < emp.salary
);
```

A `NOT EXISTS` query can also be written as an anti-join. This is: outer join the lesser earning employees; then remove from your results all employees where you found such persons.

```
select *
from emp
left join emp less on less.department_id = emp.department_id and less.salary < emp.salary
where less.employee_id is null;
```

You would usually not do this, though, because it's a trick, and it's a bit obfuscated what the query is actually doing. `NOT EXISTS` is clearer here, asking "give me employees for which not exist collegues who earn less".

(Well, in your case you might even use something entirely else, such as `where (department_id, salary) in (select department_id, min(salary) ...`) or `rank() over partition by department_id order by salary`.)

But anti joins are a solution when your DBMS proves weak on `not exists` queries. They are simply another way to write the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT D.employee_id,D.Last_name,D.salary,D.department_id
FROM [HelpDatabase].[dbo].[Employees] D,
     (SELECT department_id, MIN(salary) min_salary
      FROM [HelpDatabase].[dbo].[Employees] 
      WHERE department_id is not null
      GROUP BY department_id) E
WHERE D.department_id IS NOT NULL
  AND D.salary=E.min_salary
  AND E.department_id=D.department_id
```

You can use *min(salary) over(partition by department_id) min_salary* to get min_salary, but it will still produce subqueries and you'll have to filter rows after that

Comment: Missing an `E.department_id=D.department_id`.  Also this uses a subquery.

Comment: I added distinct to it, to work properly. Seems correct, not as mine in example, but it's still two select, not one.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT D.employee_id,D.Last_name,MIN(D.salary),D.department_id
    FROM [HelpDatabase].[dbo].[Employees] D
    WHERE D.department_id IS NOT NULL 
     group by D.employee_id,D.Last_name,D.department_id
```

Comment: It doesn't work correctly, however I'm not sure why.

Comment: Grouping by employee_id will result in a single employee in each group